# Get type of implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, type-deduction

How can I get the return type of an implicit conversion of an object?

```
struct Bar {
  operator int() const {
    return 0;
  }
};

// std::result_of<Bar>::type value; ???
// std::result_of<Bar::operator ??? >::type value;
```

I could use:

```
std::is_convertible<Bar, int>::value
```

but is_convertible is also true for float, unsigned int etc.... I would like to have the exact type.

Edit: Because my question seems unclear, why I want to know the implicit conversion type. Please think a step further to template classes. So i do not know Bar at all...

```
template<typename T, typename Sfinae = void>
struct ImplicitType
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T) != sizeof(T), "Unknown type.");
};

template<typename T>
struct ImplicitType<T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, int>::value && std::is_class<T>::value>::type>
{
  using type = int;
};

template<typename T>
struct ImplicitType<T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, float>::value && std::is_class<T>::value>::type>
{
  using type = int;
};

struct Foo
   operator float() const {
     return 0.0f;
   }
};

struct Bar {
   operator int() const {
     return 0;
   }
};

ImplicitType<Foo> r; // <--- ambiguous template instantiation
ImplicitType<Bar> r; // <--- ambiguous template instantiation
```

For Foo I would like to get float. For Bar int.

But because I can define one or more implicit conversions for class, it gets tricky.

```
struct FooBar {
  operator float() const {
     return 0;
   }

   operator int() const {
     return 0;
   }
};
```

[Not working live example.](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4AuBPADgg%2BmgJwEMQ0BnAPiWoCga0EBbLKIh9bBMIx5AFQA0STDm68kAZQBm4IsgC8SAG4B7EHAo1q1MoRgQ0SAJLMoICKT6ct2gN43tSXW3O4iZMggJoAFGRAAXggqUj58AJRIAISK/kEhYeFCAEQAqmAA1mAqAO5gwpwAdMnhANwOSAC%2B5RUMpmwIHKI8/JqOugT6hiYs5pacKIIVjiJcLU5ocABcU2MARlB4IFIoutNTIGS4ECpgSl5oIAuNgkjgaBQzSkSwyABkdxPrm9usHoOXU9e3n6NtdsMkDB/GAAOYFHBIRTncqOap0EZMFgNJpjcR8f46PQGYymPpoKw4QYCQHUUZiZBrGbzRa4ZarSYzF47PYHI6LYlIKRQFRsT7fGD3R5UjZbaDuMgfK43QW/TiYpD2RzUYHgcGjKFnMBoWHaeEVDpdJAAMRUKkVgJUOGIaBUBC5PLYPkiLN0FuVjgICDQMAI%2BQADLrlZUKvr2tjDAAhIj2pUeq1eNh2rW%2BF27N1xj1IL0%2Bv1IQOkkNwmrhzo400qaOxy3WpP27m81NIV2GTMenO%2BgNBuGA0kJm3J87O5vp1uk6gdvMFrNFvU1Gg9MwWAkDCtUAjlRf4wmNKvrzd45c7lAVvfZ0pAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

So all in all it is not possible to get the right implicit conversation type of a class?

Comment: decltype() and auto?

Comment: ***decltype<Bar()>*** is Bar and ***auto f = Bar;*** is Bar.

Comment: Bar b;
decltype((int)b) x = (int)b;

Comment: Implicit conversion to what? In your case it is clear, but what would be the desired result if there were more than 1 conversion operator?

Comment: @Vasiliy Soshnikov So I have to know the type before...? Bad.
(a)anderas Good point... well so I cant get the type?

Comment: @Viatorus yes, or you need store type inside class i.e. Bar { typedef int my_conv_type; }

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. `operator int()` has return type `int`, you don't need any fancy footwork to get that.

Comment: I edit my the question. Please look if you understand me now. If I don´t know Bar (inside a template class), how can I know if Bar has an operator int().

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
struct Bar {
    operator int() const {
        return 0;
    }
    operator double() const {
        return 0.0;
    }

    struct Foo {

    };
    operator Foo() const {
        return Foo();
    }
};
int main() {
    std::cout << typeid( decltype((int)Bar()) ).name();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid( decltype((double)Bar()) ).name();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid( decltype((Bar::Foo)Bar()) ).name();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

According to that fact, that function `Bar::operator int()` is a member function of class `Bar`, you guarantee, that there is a `this` reference for it, so that's why I provide a default object `Bar()` for all the stuff.

The result is:

```
i
d
N3Bar3FooE
```

Comment: `decltype( (int)X )` always gives `int&` , nothing to do with `Bar` ... although OP's question is unclear

Comment: OP's question is unclear, but obviously it is not: "What is the return type of Anything::operator int()". It would be nice if someone also answered about implicit conversions at all.

Comment: I edit my the question. Please look if you understand me now. I don´t know Bar so a (C)-Cast is not possible.